# Excel - Referencing external workbooks with relative file paths

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks in the same folder. I reference a cell from one workbook to another eg

```
='[WorkbookB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

When I save and close the two files, once I reopen them the formula has changed to a hardcoded path eg

```
='C:\Users\Me\Documents\[WorkbookB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Then if I move the two files to another folder, the link breaks. Is there a way to keep the file paths relative, so as long as the two workbooks are in the same folder then it will still work? I've searched around and can't even work out if this is the expected behaviour as I've found people with the exact opposite problem, but this is how it's played out for me and I haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured it out. The default behaviour is for the links to be relative, as I wanted. They weren't working because I moved both the files on to the desktop to test them out. Turns out they need to be in a folder otherwise excel can't find them.